# Multiple addEventListener not storing unique callbacks

Tags: javascript, dom

Super sleepy and coding, not a good combination, if I was a surgeon, my patient would have passed away long time ago! So here goes my 1st question on this site:

My code:

```
function cAction(manipulatedElement) {
    console.log(manipulatedElement); //test parameter
    // some manipulation code...
}

var cboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-toppings');

l = cboxes.length;
for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    cboxes[i].addEventListener('change',
        function() { cAction(i); },
        false
    );
}
```

When I check/uncheck a checkbox I only get "34" (the last checkbox) written to the console no matter which one is checked what gives?  Shouldn't each event listener's callback remember the index number "i"?

Hope someone can help me with this.

Some HTML pasted from project:

```
<div class="toppings col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox"><label>
        <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            class="checkbox-toppings" 
            id="topp1010" 
            value=""
            data-price="300"
        >
        <span class="toppings-text">pepperoni</span>
    </label></div>
</div>

<div class="toppings col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox"><label>
        <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            class="checkbox-toppings" 
            id="topp1020" 
            value=""
            data-price="300"
        >
        <span class="toppings-text">ham</span>
    </label></div>
</div> 

<!-- and 32 more items like this -->
```

Comment: Maybe a small fragment of HTML would help to put this code in context?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax HTML added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.bind` to create a different function for each callback.

```
function cAction(manipulatedElement) {
    console.log(manipulatedElement); //test parameter
    // some manipulation code...
}

var cboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-toppings');
l = cboxes.length;
for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
    cboxes[i].addEventListener('change', cAction.bind(cboxes[i], i), false);
}
```

Comment: This is works!  Thank you very much @bevacqua, been trying to Google this problem for more than 2hrs...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the concept of `Closures`.

the value of `i` is being captured or closed over by your handler ,so only the last value of `i` will get assigned.

change

```
 function(){cAction(i);}
```

to

```
(function(temp){return function(){
  cAction(temp);
}}(i))
```